# How do I create a 3D surface plot in R?

Tags: r

I am working with multiple linear regression.

I have z output which is a result of a x*y interaction.

I would like to create a surface plot of these data, but haven't had any luck.
I have tried the commandoes wireframe and persp, but it seems like I'm not able to design my commandoes yet.

I have created a beautiful scatterplot3d, but how can I create a surface plot of the same data?

Comment: Welcom to SO. Even if you get an answer, please read this: [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Plot Regression Surface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7863906/plot-regression-surface)  and also search SO for `scatter3d` which offers possibility of rgl graphics with point and surface, rather than the static versions provided by `scatterplot3d`

Answer (score 4):

I assume you know what you're doing when you say you've fitted a 3D surface in a linear regression. What `persp` and `wireframe` expect is a grid of x and y values, along with the predicted z-heights at each of those grid points. You can generate this using `expand.grid`. Here's an indicative example.

```
preddf <- expand.grid(x=seq(xmin, xmax, len=51),
                      y=seq(ymin, ymax, len=51))

preddf$z <- predict(model, preddf)

persp(preddf)
```

Replace `xmin`, `xmax`, `ymin` and `ymax` with the ranges of your predictors, and 51 with the desired size/density of your grid.

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative to `expand.grid` is to use `outer`,it is faster.

Using @HongOoi data:

```
z <- outer(x,y, function(x,y) 
  predict(mod,data.frame(x=x,y=y)))
persp(x,y,z)
```