# how to change the gradient of colour in bplot for R

Tags: r, plot, lattice

I was wondering if anybody had much experience with the function bplot in R, I am making a 3d plot and the plot works fine. The only thing I want to change is the gradient of colour which you get from drape=TRUE. At the moment it has a single pink colour fading into blue, I really need a third colour in the middle to highlight the central data better as this is the most important for my study, and at the moment in some of the plots I am doing its too difficult to pick out and correlate with the level of y in the colour scale bar.

Does anybody have any idea how to do this?

I need more reputation to post an image of the plot but you can see what I mean in the second image of this thread.
[Plot Regression Surface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7863906/plot-regression-surface/7864088#7864088)

Many thanks
Aaron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a `colorRampPalette` argument to your plot like so:

```
col.regions = colorRampPalette(colors=c("red","yellow"))(1000)
```

This will give you a gradient of 1000 shades between red and yellow, You can use any of the R colors in the color ramp, and you can specify more than two  e.g.`colors=c("red","orange3","palegoldenrod")` if you like.  You should put this argument at the same place you are putting `drape=TRUE`